# Use parameter in function passed to google.setOnLoadCallback();

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google Visualization API to display data gathered from a MySQL server. I want to get the data using PHP and then pass it into the javascript function call to create a chart. When I do this, I'm having a problem passing parameters to the function passed to google.setOnLoadCallback();. I'm fairly new to web programming, so bear with me. The working code (pretty much from their docs) looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addRows(4);
    data.setValue(0, 0, '2004');
    data.setValue(0, 1, 1000);
    data.setValue(1, 0, '2005');
    data.setValue(1, 1, 1170);
    data.setValue(2, 0, '2006');
    data.setValue(2, 1, 660);
    data.setValue(3, 0, '2007');
    data.setValue(3, 1, 1000);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, title: 'Company Performance',
                      hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
                     });
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was trying to first see if I could set up the data outside of the drawChart() function and pass it as a parameter as so:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

  var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data1.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data1.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data1.addRows(4);
    data1.setValue(0, 0, '2004');
    data1.setValue(0, 1, 1000);
    data1.setValue(1, 0, '2005');
    data1.setValue(1, 1, 1170);
    data1.setValue(2, 0, '2006');
    data1.setValue(2, 1, 660);
    data1.setValue(3, 0, '2007');
    data1.setValue(3, 1, 1000);

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(data1));

  function drawChart(data) {
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, title: 'Company Performance',
                      hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
                     });
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not too sure why this doesn't work. What would be the best way to create the DataTable object using dynamically gathered data from a PHP MySQL call? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following are the steps to make it work:

1. Place google.load and google.setOnLoadCallback in a separate script tag.
2. Use a function expression.

Here is the working code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { drawChart(data1); });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data1.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data1.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data1.addRows(4);
    data1.setValue(0, 0, '2004');
    data1.setValue(0, 1, 1000);
    data1.setValue(1, 0, '2005');
    data1.setValue(1, 1, 1170);
    data1.setValue(2, 0, '2006');
    data1.setValue(2, 1, 660);
    data1.setValue(3, 0, '2007');
    data1.setValue(3, 1, 1000);

  function drawChart(data) {
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, title: 'Company Performance',
                      hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
                     });
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: we don't need separate script tags. it works fine in a single tag

Answer (score 48):

in the first example you pass in the function to the callback, in the second example you **call** the function and then pass in the result of that call to the callback.

try:

```
setOnLoadCallback(function(){ drawChart(data) })
```

Comment: I did this and tested with dummy variable, successfully passing them. But for some reason when I attempt to create the DataTable outside of the function and pass that as the param, it doesn't like it.